# color of clicked button show over given multiple button in android

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout

I am working on an Android app.

I want to have 3 buttons placed horizontally at the top of the screen like tab view.

For these 3 buttons, the color of clicked button should be `red` and all remaining buttons in default state.

For example:

when user clicks on a button, the color of the clicked button should turn `red`.

when user clicks on another button then the color of the clicked button should turn `red` and the previous button's color should return to `default state`, like each button depends one to another.

Comment: did you have buttons on your xml or add the buttons from code

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.btn_1:
        btn_1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.selected_color);
        btn_2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.default_color);
        btn_3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.default_color);
        btn_4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.default_color);
        break;
    case R.id.btn_2:
        btn_2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.selected_color);
        btn_1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.default_color);
        btn_3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.default_color);
        btn_4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.default_color);
        break;
    case R.id.btn_3:
        btn_3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.selected_color);
        btn_2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.default_color);
        btn_1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.default_color);
        btn_4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.default_color);
        break;
    case R.id.btn_4:
        btn_4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.selected_color);
        btn_2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.default_color);
        btn_3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.default_color);
        btn_1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.default_color);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: @devendra if my solution is work for you then accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use this solution! Android provides an other way which is perfect and clean.

You should create a select(xml file) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:background="@color/you_color" />
</selector>
```

and then in you button do like this

```
<android:background="@drawable/your_selector">
```